# Is there any way to select the last process of multiple processes in a pool to perform an extra task?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Is there any way that I can let the last process run in func(x) perform extra task other than return x*x?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(x):
    # to let the last process run here perform extra task other than return x*x
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(func, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: What kind of task? Also a mathematical operation on a number?

Comment: yes. for example to empty a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do that would be if somehow `func` knew what the last element of the *iterable* being used in the `Pool.map` method was and there is no clean way to do that. Why not just submit a separate task to handle the extra work that needs to be done for the last value? Assuming that everything could run in parallel you would want to use `map_async` and `apply_async` for these two respective tasks and if you want the results to print out as soon as soon as either one completes, then you should specify one or more callback routines depending on whether the extra work performed for the last element of the *iterable* requires something to be printed out or some result returned:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(x):
    # to let the last process run here perform extra task other than return x*x
    return x*x

def func2(x):
    # perform extra function with last argument
    ...

def callback1(result):
    """ return value from map_async(func, etc.) """
    print(result)

def callback2(result):
    """ return value from func2 """
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as p: # you only need 4 processes
        p.map_async(func, [1, 2, 3], callback=callback1)
        # provide argument to func2, if needed, and a callback, if needed
        p.apply_async(func2, args=(3,), callback=callback2)
        # wait for both of the above submitted tasks to complete:
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

If you don't care about printing out results as soon as they are available, then you do not need to use callback functions:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as p: # you only need 4 processes
        result1 = p.map_async(func, [1, 2, 3])
        # provide argument to func2, if needed
        result2 = p.apply_async(func2, args=(3,))
        # wait for both of the above submitted tasks to complete:
        print(result1.get()) # return value from map call
        print(result2.get()) # or just result2.get() if return value is not interesting
```

If, however, the extra processing to be done for the last argument should only take place after the `map` call completes, then that extra processing should be run by the main process and no callback functions are required:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(3) as p: # you only need 3 processes
        print(p.map(func, [1, 2, 3])
        func2(3)
```

Comment: Did this answer your question satisfactorily?